# Is an editable content query possible?

Tags: document-library, content-query-web-part

I am using our SharePoint site as a learning management system for training newly hired employees.  Our set us is a subsite that contains 25 site pages (one for each student).  Each page contains a unique Document web part so that each student has a unique copy of a curriculum document (an editable PDF).  Right now, I create each class as a template but when I update curriculum items, I have to update it in all 25 document libraries.  I'm wondering if there is a way to dynamically populate the document libraries (like a content query) from a central library?  I'd use a content query but you can't have your own copy of the document that I know of.  If Student 1 checks out something, Student 2 can't and if they could, they would overwrite Student 1's work.  I'm hoping for a more automated way to populate each document library.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could just create a manual workflow that will copy the pdf or items to each site.

Comment: That's interesting Chris.  So (forgive me if I'm about to sound dumb), could a customer workflow act as a type of "script" that will do this work for me?  Could a workflow be programed to create a "class" and assign the content?

Comment: That's correct.  SP has a workflow that I have used that copies one item, and can copy that into several places.  I'd like to be able to select multiple documents and do the same thing.